# Default initializers for same datatype multiple variable declaration in Swift

Tags: swift

I would like to use a default initializer on each of these variables of same type. How would I do that?  Typically I would declare one at a time like this: var red = UILabel(); var yellow = UILabel()

```
class myViewController: UIViewController {

    var red, yellow, green, blue, pink, orange: UILabel

    func addButtonsToView() {
     view.addSubview(red) // etc...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still have to initialize them each individually, but at least you can do them all in one declaration like this:

```
var (red, yellow, green, blue, pink, orange) = (UILabel(), UILabel(), UILabel(), UILabel(), UILabel(), UILabel())
```